# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token android browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, responsive-design

I'm using the [pgwmenu](http://pgwjs.com/pgwmenu/) libraries to change the menu style when entering on responsive mode.
using the responsive modes on the desktop browsers works great, along with the chrome and firefox android version and iphone's safari, but in the native android browser it doesn't do anything.

using the javascript console I get this error

on pgwmenu.jquery.json on line 2

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

this is its code of that pgwmenu.jquery.json, I haven't altered it:

```
{
"name": "pgwmenu",
"title": "PgwMenu",
"description": "Responsive menu plugin for jQuery",
"keywords": [
    "menu",
    "navigation",
    "dropdown"
    "responsive",
    "mobile",
    "ui",
],
"version": "2.0.0",
"author": {
    "name": "Jonathan M. Piat"
},
"maintainers": [
    {
        "name": "Jonathan M. Piat"
    }
],
"licenses": [
    {
        "type": "GNU GPLv3",
        "url": "http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-3.0"
    }
],
"bugs": "https://github.com/Pagawa/PgwMenu/issues",
"homepage": "http://pgwjs.com/pgwmenu",
"docs": "http://pgwjs.com/pgwmenu",
"download": "http://pgwjs.com/pgwmenu",
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">=1"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no comma after `"dropdown"` in 8th line

Comment: yeah I saw that and added the comma, but still nothing works.

Comment: One more thing remove comma after `"ui"`. And a suggestion use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json.

Comment: removed the comma, and it says it's valid, but still same error on javascript console